# PPP persist connection ( 3G network auto reconnect on pppd )

Tags: linux, networking, ppp

I have a machine that needs all time connection to 3G network.
I'm able to connect and stay online, but ISP closes connection like every 24h, for that I need a persist connection. 
I´ve set the option persist on pppd, but it will not bring up the connection up again automatically.

When a pppd session is disconnected it triggers some udev script to ifdown the ppp link which kills pppd and stopping a reconnection.

It is said that the script that do that is   /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ifupdown.rules
But I dont have this 85-ifupdown.rules on my ubuntu

Any help to solve this not presist connection is welcome

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The scripts used by pppd during connection setup and break down are in /etc/ppp/if-up.d if-down.d

What version of pppd do you use?

Comment: I see directory names as /etc/ppp/ip-up.d ip-down.d on ubuntu-14.04